# Using SED to replaces leading and trailing spces in a csv file

Tags: sed

I am using the following command to strip leading and trailing spaces from a file A.csv

```
sed "s/^  \+//g;s/[ \t]*$//;s/ \{1,\}/ /g" <A.csv> B.csv
```

Here is an example to A.csv

```
"a","  v b","z"
"a","   vd","z"
"a","  v, b, c ","z  "
"a","  vb ","z   "
```

The problem is that not all leading and trailing spaces are removed as shown below:

```
"a"," v b","z"
"a"," vd","z"
"a"," v, b, c ","z "
"a"," vb ","z "
```

Below is an example of what I was expecting:

```
"a","v b","z"
"a","vd","z"
"a","v, b, c","z"
"a","vb","z"
```

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/" \+/"/g;s/[ \t]*"/"/g;s/ \{1,\}/ /g' A.csv
```

The ouput:

```
"a","v b","z"
"a","vd","z"
"a","v, b, c","z"
"a","vb","z"
```

Your own command, only `s/ \{1,\}/ /g` is working.
Thing is, sed will treat csv file as a simple text file, without knowing the commas and quotes are for columns.
So the `^` and `$` will only match the beginning and the end of each line.
Also you forgot to put `g` to the second `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't do this properly with just `sed`. I recommend switching to some better language that can work with `CSV` files.

There is also a tool called `csvtool`:

```
$ cat /path/to/trim
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
for c; do
    c=${c##*([[:space:]])} c=${c%%*([[:space:]])}
    printf '"%s"\n' "${c//'"'/'""'}"
done | paste -sd,

$ csvtool call /path/to/trim A.csv
"a","v b","z"
"a","vd","z"
"a","v, b, c","z"
"a","vb","z"
```

As much as I like `csvtool` for simple stuff, this will unfortunately be **painfully** slow! It took my VBox nearly 15 seconds to process a short 4000-line `CSV`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"\s*([^[:space:]"]+(\s*[^[:space:]"]+)*)\s*"/"\1"/g' file
```

Remove immediate white space either side of a pair of double quotes, globally throughout the file.